# How to get the graph between false acceptance rate and false rejection rate for the mnist dataset in python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I need to find the False acceptance rate and false rejection rate for this 10*10 confusion matrix I got for the mnist digit classification and then I need to plot graph between them.
here is my code for the confusion matrix:

```
test_predictions = model.predict_classes(test_images)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true = test_labels, y_pred = test_predictions)
print(cm)
```

Comment: false acceptance rate and false rejection rate makes sense for a binary classification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix).

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(estimator=model, X=test_images, y=test_labels)
```